# Define path to Gradle Wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

To not clutter my project's top-level directory I would like the gradle wrapper JAR to land in a subdirectory, e.g. `infra`. I'm going for something like this:

```
root
 L .infra
    L gradle
       L wrapper
          L gradle-wrapper.jar
          L gradle-wrapper.properties
```

I hoped that `archiveBase` or `distributionBase` would get me there but even if brute forcing these settings, I still end up with `gradle` in the top level.

```
configure(rootProject) {

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        description = 'Generates gradlew and gradlew.bat scripts'
        gradleVersion = '3.2'
        archiveBase = Wrapper.PathBase.PROJECT
        archivePath = ".infra/"
        distributionBase = Wrapper.PathBase.PROJECT
        distributionPath = ".infra/"
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One drawback of a custom directory layout is that other people will not find their way so easily.

Comment: I agree but as I understand it, the `gradle` folder contains nothing that one has to interact with directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These paths will be set in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

```
distributionBase=PROJECT
distributionPath=infra/ <---- 
zipStoreBase=PROJECT
zipStorePath=infra/ <----
```

You can set the path to **wrapper script** and **jar** by using following properties.

```
jarFile = "${project.projectDir}/.infra/gradle-wrapper.jar" // archive
scriptFile = "${project.projectDir}/.infra/gradlew" // wrapper script
```

Comment: But I don't want the file to be in `gradle/wrapper`, I want it in `.infra/gradle/wrapper` to begin with.